# Do linear and logistic regression on R take range?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I've encountered challenges when using a glm and lm in R that they don't accept range of variables.

For example my code is this

```
model1 = glm(RESPONSE~., train.df, family= "binomial")
summary(model1)
```

RESPNSE is a variable name on the dataset. I am aware that the dot"." means all variables.

Is there away that I can tell R to take a range of variables, for example from 1 to N? N = integer numbers

The reason asking this question is because I need to include many, it takes a lot of time to type all of them with no mistakes.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Subset the data you give to `glm`: `glm(RESPONSE ~ ., data = traind.df[, c(col_number_of_response, 1:N)], family = "binomial")`

Comment: You can also paste together formulas, `glm(as.formula(paste("RESPONSE ~", paste(names([train.df])[1:N], collapse = " + "))), data = train.df, family = "binomial")`

Comment: Thanks, but what collapse= “ +” do exactly?

Comment: `collapse` is an argument to `paste`.  See `?paste` ...  @GregorThomas, can you please post these  comments as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built in anscombe data frame this regresses y1 on the range from x3 to x4.  The variable names can be replaced with column numbers or even a mix of variable names and column numbers.

```
lm(y1 ~ ., subset(anscombe, select = c(y1, x3:x4)))

lm(y1 ~ ., subset(anscombe, select = c(5, 3:4)))
```

We can alternately express this using pipes:

```
anscombe |>
  subset(select = c(y1, x3:x4)) |>
  lm(y1 ~ ., data = _)
```

Using dplyr it is nearly the same:

```
library(dplyr)
anscombe %>%
  select(y1, x3:x4) %>%
  lm(y1 ~ ., data = .)
```